# Can't type the Caret Character (^) in TexMacs to denote exponentiation

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, tex, maxima

The caret character `^` does not print on screen in TexMacs (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Maxima 5.24.0).

It works fine in all other programs.

Is there another way to denote exponentiation in TeXMacs?

Comment: Try `\^{}`. It seems like TeXMacs interprets the input using LaTeX, where `^` has special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean when you say the caret doesn't print. I am using TeXmacs 1.0.7.7 + Maxima 5.22.1 + Ubuntu 11.04, and when I type, say, 2^n, I see "2^n" displayed as input, and the typeset form (2 superscript n) as the output. So I can't reproduce the problem.

The internal operator for exponentiation is MEXPT in Lisp. You can enter it as ?mexpt, e.g. ?mexpt(2, n) is the same as 2^n.